# Selenium PhantomJS: Loading Pages in Different Windows in Parallel

Tags: python, selenium, download, phantomjs

Is it possible to control selenium such that it opens multiple pages in parallel in separate windows?

Selenium's `get` command waits until the `onload` event gets fired, but I'd like to initiate the page load sequence and continue without waiting for `onload`. Below is basically what I'd like to do, but it requires `get_url_async` and `wait_for_onload`, which are two commmands I just made up.

```
# Step 1: Initiate all of the page downloads
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
  # Is it possible to initiate a page get without waiting for onload?
  driver.get_url_async(url)

# Step 2: Wait for the pages to download.
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
  # This function does not exist, any way to implement something similar?
  driver.wait_for_onload()
  # Do more processing of the page here
```

Another option is to open up separate webdriver instances, but I want these instances to be able to share cookies and state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can open a window asynchronously by executing the `window.open` javascript. Using that function, you can access multiple pages in parallel simultaneously. After initiating the download, you can implement your own waiting logic to determine when the page has finished loading.

```
def download_parallel(urls, driver, process_page):
  '''Download pages in parallel using Selenium
  urls: a list of urls to download
  driver: The selenium webdriver
  process_page: a function that takes in the url and the driver to process 
                the page as you see fit.
  '''
  start_handle = driver.current_window_handle
  handles = []

  # Step 1: Initiate all of the page downloads
  for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    old_handles = driver.window_handles
    # Initiate a page get without waiting for onload
    driver.execute_script('window.open("%s", "para_win_%02d", '
            '"height = 450, width = 800, menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,'
            'location=no,resizable=yes");'%(url, i))
    # We have to determine the handle for the new window.
    for h in driver.window_handles:
      if h not in old_handles:
        handles.append(h)
        break

  # Step 2: Wait for the pages to download.
  for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.switch_to.window(handles[i])
    # Wait for some css to load. There are other waiting functions you can use.
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
      EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body #my_main"))
    )
    # Do more processing of the page here
    process_page(url, driver)
    # Close the window now that we're done with it.
    driver.close()

  # Go back to the window we started in
  driver.switch_to.window(start_handle)
```